# Tamanho de um ArrayList

Tags: java, array

Em Java...

- Qual o tamanho inicial de um `ArrayList`?
- Atingindo o tamanho máximo, quando ele se "expande", seu tamanho é duplicado?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A capacidade inicial é de 10 elementos, se não for especificada na criação do objeto. E quando atinge o máximo ele é realocado transparentemente (implementação interna) com o dobro da capacidade atual se a nova capacidade for suficiente para o que vai fazer.

A duplicação da capacidade ao invés de alocar só a necessidade é feita para minimizar um problema semelhante ao do [`Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm`](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) onde uma nova pequena adição ao `ArrayList` já produziria uma nova realocação, tornando a operação cada vez mais lenta. O algoritmo troca uma quantidade exagerada de realocações por um possível desperdício de memória.

Tem algo falando disto no SO [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8896758/221800) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10794890/221800). A [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) diz que a capacidade inicial é 10, então isto provavelmente não mudará, documentou, vira contrato :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Se o *ArrayList* tem 10 posições alocadas, ao se adicionar um novo elemento ela aumenta 50% seu valor; já as *Linkedlist*, aumentam em 100%.