# Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?

Tags: .net, gerenciamento-de-memória, memory-leaks

Sei que o CLR conta com ferramentas como *garbage collector*, responsável pelo gerenciamento da memória nas aplicações .NET. Uma das funções do coletor de lixo, GC, é evitar o consumo desnecessário da memória.

Mesmo com a ferramenta, por diversos motivos, surge o vazamento de memória. É a memória alocada de forma desnecessária que com o tempo pode causar um `OutOfMemoryException`. O problema maior é que essa exceção não será disparada aonde está o *memory leak*, e sim na linha de código que o programa não tiver mais memória suficiente pra poder alocar.

Como identificar esses vazamentos na aplicação .NET e que práticas adotar para evitá-los?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## O que é *memory leak*?

Podemos dizer que o vazamento de memória ocorre toda vez que existe uma memória alocada mais tempo que o necessário. Isso costuma ocorrer porque o código (ou mais precisamente o programador que o escreveu) se perdeu e esquece de liberar a memória depois que ela não é mais necessária. Há desperdício de memória, e o acumulo de desperdícios pode levar a inviabilizar a execução por causa de tanta memória que a aplicação está ocupando.

Na verdade tem um problema até maior que é liberar memória prematuramente que ainda precisa ser acessada, mas o assunto aqui é outro.

Com um coletor de lixo do mais comum é normal os objetos não serem liberados logo em seguida que eles não são mais necessários. A coleta ocorre de tempos em tempos conforme a necessidade de memória. Há um certo desperdício, mas ele é *by design*. Quando se usa algo como um *garbage collector* abrimos mão de ter a maior economia de memória possível. Mas não podemos abrir mão de ter memória não mais necessária ficar sem liberação.

Quando há um GC a definição de vazamento de memória varia um pouco. Apenas os objetos que sobrevivem a uma coleta mesmo não sendo mais necessário de fato é que é considerado vazamento. Antes de ter uma coleta é considerado normal que o objeto esteja ali mesmo não sendo necessário mais.

Se tiver muito vazamento, mais cedo ou mais tarde receberá uma [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0).

Em aplicações que rodam por pouco tempo pode ter vazamentos que nunca são percebidos, alguns inócuos, outros nem tanto.

Que fique claro que não há vazamentos que são alocados na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), essa memória tem gerenciamento automático.

#### Por que o GC não coleta algo que já é desnecessário?

Não é porque ele é ruim. É porque o código tem algum problema e mantém pelo menos uma referência para um objeto que de fato não é mais necessário, mas o que o código está dizendo é que ele é necessário. Isso pode ocorrer por algumas razões que veremos abaixo.

#### Tenho que reiniciar o computador para liberar a memória vazada?

Não. Ao final da aplicação o sistema operacional liberará toda memória vinculada a ela, mesmo que sua aplicação não o faça. Ele faz isso perfeita e completamente todas as vezes, até porque foi ele que deu memória para sua aplicação, ele sabe tudo o que foi dado para pegar de volta.

## Memória gerenciada

De fato o .NET trabalha com um gerenciador de memória, que contrariamente ao nome, se preocupa mais com a forma de alocação do que a liberação de memória. Isso facilita muito o desenvolvimento da aplicação já que é um enorme transtorno gerenciar a memória corretamente, especialmente quando usamos recursos mais avançados da linguagem e biblioteca.

O .NET possui um GC muito esperto e permite alocações ao custo próximo ao da alocação em *stack* (que é absurdamente rápido) e não tem custo de liberação. Mas tem as pausas de coleta. Além disso ele mantém a memória sem fragmentos, o que ajuda manter localidade de referência que proporciona melhor performance.

O problema é que muitos programadores acham que por causa disso não precisamos nos preocupar com nada no uso da memória. Temos várias perguntas aqui no SOpt onde usuários relatam vazamento de memória.

## Memória não gerenciada

[Nem toda memória alocada na sua aplicação é gerenciada pelo coletor de lixo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#overloads). Você pode usar bibliotecas e serviços do sistema operacional que alocam memória por conta própria e o .NET não tem controle direto sobre essa alocação, só esse componente que alocou pode liberar a memória e normalmente ele precisa ser avisado que sua aplicação não precisa mais desse conteúdo alocado.

O mecanismo que o .NET adotou para dar esse aviso é o *disposable pattern*. Todo objeto que acesse recursos externos à memória gerenciada deve implementar o método `Dispose()` da interface `IDisposable`. Neste método é feito todo o trabalho necessário para liberar [todos recursos alocados fora da memória gerenciada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101).

Note que a memória gerenciada do objeto não é liberada, isso só ocorrerá quando o GC disparar uma coleta.

Para garantir que o [`Dispose()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101) seja sempre chamado é importante colocá-lo dentro de um `finally` de um `try`. Ou melhor ainda, usar o *statement* [`using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145858/101) que monta um escopo onde o objeto precisa da memória não gerenciada e garantidamente chama o método ao seu final.

Se criar um objeto *disposable* sem o `using` ou chamar o método manualmente de forma garantida, haverá vazamento de memória.

Tem muitas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Método para executar ao destruir instância de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41175/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)
- [Método Dispose()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Liberar memória de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414237/101)
- [Como garantir que a instanciação de uma classe seja feita apenas através do "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54143/101)
- [Diferença entre instanciar classe e using](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422273/101)
- [O HttpClient deve, ou não deve, ser utilizado dentro de um bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422717/101)

#### Ufa, que bom que eu sempre faço isso e não corro riscos

Não é bem assim. Tem objetos que você tem que implementar o `Dispose()`. É verdade que isso não é tão comum na maioria das aplicações, em geral você só consome essas classes, afinal quase sempre o acesso ao recurso será feito por uma API em C ou outra linguagem não gerenciada. Mas se tiver que fazer uma classe assim terá que liberar o recurso gerenciado de maneira apropriada de acordo com o componente que está usando. O método não libera nada magicamente. Liberar corretamente memória não gerenciada nem sempre é intuitivo. Mas há casos que é simples e o próprio sistema operacional faz para você simplesmente sinalizando que está encerrando.

Como eu disse, esse padrão é um sinalizador que algo deve ser feito para jogar fora algo não mais necessário.

Um dos erros mais comuns que vejo as pessoas fazerem é criar uma classe para gerenciar conexão. Alguém ensinou isso errado um dia e todo mundo passou fazer errado. Primeiro que em geral essa classe não ajuda muito, e segundo que ela tem um recurso que deve ser descartado. Esse padrão de *dispose* é viral, ou seja, se você usá-lo em um objeto ele obrigatoriamente deve se tornar *disposable*.

#### E se eu esquecer de usar o `using` fico com o vazamento até o fim da aplicação?

Talvez não. Todos objetos do .NET possuem um método `Finalize()` que acaba sendo chamado pelo GC quando um objeto é coletado e se ele estiver escrito certo acabará matando o vazamento, mas ainda podemos dizer que houve vazamento por ter ficado vivo mais tempo do que deveria.

Nada garante que o finalizador será executado alguma vez. E é até um pouco comum que ele não seja chamado por nunca ter o objeto coletado. O objeto gerenciado não faz *cosquinha* na memória, por isso não causa grande pressão no GC, mas o recurso não gerenciado que ele referencia costuma ocupar bastante espaço e causa estrago. Sem falar que ele talvez deveria ser fechado para outro usar, quando é exclusivo, e isso não ocorre.

Outro problema de deixar para liberar o recurso durante a coleta é que ela demorará mais.

É raro acontecer, mas um código pode [suprimir a finalização](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_GC_SuppressFinalize_System_Object_) indevidamente. Não tão raro assim é um [finalizador impedir outros de executarem](https://alexatnet.com/articles/memory-leaks-in-net-applications/event-handlers).

## Objetos referenciados

Eventualmente algum objeto, especialmente grande, acaba sendo referenciado por outro objeto que vive mais tempo que esse primeiro objeto precisa sobreviver. Isso pode ser considerado, por alguns, como um vazamento.

Pode ser que colocou uma referência para ele em um objeto **estático** que provavelmente terá o tempo de vida por toda aplicação. Ou é referenciado em um objeto que fica circulando pra todo lado na aplicação sem necessidade. Ou ainda em um objeto não gerenciado que nunca é liberado.

Alguns componentes do .NET ou de bibliotecas de terceiros possuem situações assim. Ou porque foram mal feitos ou porque não existe possibilidade de fazer corretamente. É raro, mas existe. E você tem que tomar um cuidado adicional.

Um outro erro comum é o programador colocar um `null` para acabar com a referência. Quase sempre que se faz isso tem alguma coisa errada no código. Claro que existem casos que a semântica do objeto nulo é válido.

#### Eventos

Um caso típico é o uso do evento. Para quem não conhece o [`event`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101) é a implementação do [padrão Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101). Nele você referencia um delegado de outro objeto que deseja ser notificado. Se o objeto observado sobreviver mais tempo que o observador precisa, ele segurará o observador vivo sem necessidade.

```
var obj = new Classe();
// ...
obj2.Event += obj.objEventHandler;
// ...
obj = null //deveria librar para o GC coletar, mas ainda tem referência p/ ele
```

Isso pode ser resolvido removendo a assinatura de notificação quando o observador não precisa mais ficar vivo. E é raro que o tempo de vida desses objetos sejam diferentes, mas é uma possibilidade, atenção a isso. Algo assim deve ser feito:

```
obj2.Event -= obj.objEventHandler;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Memory/Event.cs).

#### *Closures*

Se você cria uma *closure*, ou seja, um delegado que faz uso de uma variável criada fora do seu escopo, essa variável será criada no *heap* (cria uma classe para sustentar a(s) variável(is)) e só perderá a referência quando o delegado deixar de existir. Isso pode demorar mais do que deveria ou nunca acontecer.

De certa forma é o mesmo problema de ter uma referência em um objeto qualquer. Mas muitas pessoas não percebem que a variável será "promovida" para o *heap* e que o delegado pode sobreviver mais do que ela pensa inicialmente.

#### Concatenação de coleções

Se tiver que concatenar muitas *strings*, cada passo na concatenação gera um novo objeto e o anterior é descartado. Isso não é exatamente um vazamento de memória clássico, mas não deixa de produzir lixo demais. Nesse caso é [melhor usar um `StringBuilder`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101).

O mesmo pode ocorrer em um `List` e outras coleções, mas o problema é um pouco diferente do ocorrido com `string`. Essas coleções foram feitas para adicionar novos itens. A coleção não gera um novo objeto em cada adição, mas gera um novo objeto logaritmicamente e podem ser objetos grandes a serem descartados. O ideal é evitar isso já [reservando espaço pelo menos próximo ao que se espera que irá consumir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54259/101) (é Java, mas o .NET é semelhante).

Se reservar espaço demais podemos considerar um pouco como vazamento, afinal algo alocado e não usado também não é bom, isso deve ser minimizado.

Ocorre com qualquer objeto imutável que exija muitas mudanças ou mudanças grandes em alguns momentos.

Não são vazamentos *per se*, mas agem quase como se fossem, acho que é importante entender porque esse tipo de uso pode causar mais problemas que alguns vazamentos reais.

#### Alocar no *heap* sem necessidade

Também não é um vazamento de memória *per se*, mas criar um objeto no *heap*  (talvez por [*boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101) indevido) alocará algo que sequer precisaria estar lá e portanto não precisaria ser coletado. É um vazamento temporário, mas pode ser ruim se feito em quantidade, e até pode por pressão indevida no GC.

Hoje tem várias formas de evitar isso, um deles é o [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

#### Cache

Cache deve ser acessado por uma referência que morrerá muito rapidamente ou por uma [referência fraca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que permite a liberação do objeto referenciado. Se isso não ocorrer poderá segurar um objeto indevidamente não só ocupando memória geral, mas também o espaço do cache que poderia ter alguma coisa mais útil.

#### *Frameworks*

O WPF e WinForms podem vazar memória no *binding*, no `Textbox` *undo*, `EventHandler` e outros.

Isto não é uma lista completa, só citei exemplos, vários *frameworks* de vários tipos vazam memória dependendo de como você usa, então ler a documentação por completo, com cuidado é necessário antes de fazer. Fazer rápido não pode ser desculpa para pular essa exigência.

#### *Thread*

Se uma *thread* não encerrar quando deveria, se entrar em *deadlock*, não só os objetos referenciados dentro dela podem viver mais do que deveria, mas a própria memória necessária para esta *thread* mantém-se viva (só a *stack* pode ter 1MB e fica todo ali, mesmo que não tenha alocações nele).

Pode ocorrer um *deadlock* por diversos motivos, inclusive esquecer de dar um [`Monitor.Exit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.exit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Threading_Monitor_Exit_System_Object_).

#### Código gerado dinamicamente

É raro fazer isso, mas se gerar muito código em tempo de execução (pode ser feito de diversas maneiras) é provável que toda memória necessária para sua criação não seja mais liberada mesmo que não precise mais deste código.

#### Fragmentação do LOH

O Large Object Heap (veja mais abaixo) não é propriamente compactado. Se o reaproveitamento dos buracos deixados forem bem menores que o ocupado antes haverá um enorme desperdício. É verdade que não ocorre tanto porque se tiver vários menores, é possível que dê para encaixar dois ou mais blocos novos no lugar de um antigo. Isso é uma preocupação rara e não exatamente um vazamento de memória, mas um desperdício que pode comprometer em casos extremos.

## Cuidado extremo

Recentemente aprendi uma "boa prática" :D para aplicações que rodam com um coletor de lixo geracional onde os **objetos devem morrer jovens ou sobreviver para sempre**.

Esses gerenciadores de memória possuem uma geração 0 curta (algo como 256KB) para garantir que a coleta dela seja feita de forma muito rápida (na casa dos microssegundos). Obviamente ele tende a encher relativamente rápido (nem tanto assim, já vi estatísticas que a maioria das aplicações possuem objetos com tamanho médio de incríveis 35 bytes já que os grandes não entram nessas gerações) e quando isto ocorre a coleta é disparada copiando todos objetos que ainda possuem referências para a geração 1. *Idealmente* não deveria copiar qualquer objeto. Claro que isso é quase impossível, mas devemos tentar que isso ocorra.

Quanto mais objetos são copiados para a Gen 1 mais rápido ele enche. Ele também é um pouco curto (uns 2MB). É feito assim para ser rápido (1 ou 2ms) e não dar pausa perceptível. Quando ele enche, tem que copiar tudo que ainda deve sobreviver para a geração 2. Novamente o ideal é copiar o mínimo possível.

A Gen 2 não tem limite teórico de tamanho. Claro que ele tenta manter tudo dentro da RAM. Mesmo a memória virtual tem seu limite, em 32 bits é de 4GB e em 64 bits é 16 Exabytes (raras as máquinas que conseguem passar de 1 TB hoje, que são 7 ordens de magnitude menores que o máximo permitido, ou se preferir, é mais ou menos toda RAM disponível em todos computadores do mundo hoje).

Demora muito, mas se essa última geração encher, a pausa será potencialmente longa. É verdade que existem técnicas para minimizar isto, como a [concorrência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101) de parte do processo, e também deve ser mais raro ter uma coleta disparada. O ideal é que raros objetos cheguem nessa geração.

Se muitos objetos chegam na Gen 2 seria melhor criar um *object pooling* preferencialmente grande o suficiente para cair no LOH e nunca ser copiado ou coletado, por exemplo pode usar [`Memory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Os objetos acima de 85000 bytes são alocados no LOH - Large Object Heap e só são compactados junto com a coleta da Gen 2. Na verdade ele não compacta no sentido de reduzir os fragmentos de memória, ele apenas libera o que não está sendo usado. Por serem objetos grandes os buracos não são um problema para a performance como o ocorre com objetos pequenos. Os buracos entram em uma *free list* para serem usados de novo por novos objetos que caibam ali, mais ou menos como ocorre na memória gerenciada pelo sistema operacional.

Claro que nem todo tipo de aplicação precisa dessa preocupação toda, a maioria não dá a percepção que existem paradas.

E o mais importante, como toda boa prática, tem que usar onde faça sentido, seja útil, e só depois de entender todas implicações. Criar um *pool* de objetos pode causar o vazamento de memória.

#### O que isto tem a ver com vazamento de memória?

Não que isso seja exatamente um vazamento clássico de memória, mas este padrão de uso de memória pode diminuir a pressão no *garbage collector*. Deixar um objeto sobreviver mais do que o necessário, mesmo que ele acabe sendo coletado não deixa de ser uma vazamento temporário.

## Como detectar

Cada problema demanda uma técnica específica. O que vai ajudar são os *perfiladores* de memória. [Já respondi algo sobre isto e listei alguns *profilers*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153878/101).

Achei uma [técnica interessante para testar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/579001/221800).

[Artigo no Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-Detecting-NET-application-memo).

[Dicas do .NET Memory Profiller](http://memprofiler.com/findmemoryleaks.aspx).

[Pergunta sobre o assunto no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134086/221800).

Em 2021/22 o GC foi reformulado e agora trata melhor certos padrões de uso dando mais eficiência em alguns casos.

Dúvidas específicas podem ser perguntadas.

Comment: O WPF, por prática, abusar o padrão Observer (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) para data binding, deve sofrer com isso. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: Não conheço a implementação específica para falar, mas tem boa possibilidade. Claro que talvez tenham pensado nisso e achado uma solução.