# Como liberar memoria em uma aplicação WPF em C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, memória, dispose

Bom eu criei um sistema em WPF e C# e a cada dia que passa ele fica maior, eu sinceramente nunca havia me preocupado com a questão de memória pra aplicações pequenas não faz muita diferença, mas não é o caso.

Ai agora tenho a seguinte situação, algumas pessoas ficam dias com o sistema aberto e ele só vai consumindo memoria até chega uma hora que estoura e ele fecha.

> Não há cota suficiente para processar este comando [Memory: 739614720]
>   em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(HandleRef hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>      em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget, Nullable`1 channelSet)
>      em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
>      em System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>      em System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      em MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>      em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Eu pesquisei um pouco e pelo que vi era para o GC fazer a "faxina" automaticamente, mas não é o que está acontecendo. Eu também chamei o Dispose em algumas classes de DataBase mas não ajudou muito também.

Eu depurei o sistema e simulei algumas situações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo que eu feche a aba ou troque a ordem de serviço eu percebi que realmente a memoria não limpa.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer para melhorar essa situação.

Eu peguei alguns logs e esse erro acontece em pessoas que ficam com o sistema vários dias aberto normalmente 2 ou 3 dias, ele não passa disso porque estoura a memoria kkk.

Numa empresa de 60 funcionários acontece umas 2 ou 3 vezes por dia ao todo, mas gostaria de otimizar o código, porque o sistema vai crescer e esse problema pode ficar serio no futuro.

Pesquisei sobre memory leak e acredito que tenha chegado ao problema

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/

Parece está relacionado ao x:Name do RadGridView, fiz alguns testes e aparentemente melhorou o cenário mas ainda estou analizando.

Comment: Olá viva, antes de entrar no mundo do GC, eu diria analisares coisas simples, e com isso podes utilizar o Visual Studio Profiler o consumo de memória, pela experiência que já tive no passado, o simples factor de um User Control ou Window estar a ser instanciada de novo cada vez que abre criava um memory leak, é por aí que vais encontrar o teu problema. Pode demorar a acontecer, um dia ou dois, mas crias uma rotina que efetue o click de abrir views repetidamente, por exemplo. Podendo ser o abrir e fechar views. Mas pode ser objetos que crescem porque não estão a ser limpos quando consultas db.

Comment: se puder, mostre o código que está usando que gera esse consumo excessivo

Comment: Você tem um problema de memory leak. Ficar com o sistema vários dias abertos não é pra dar problema. Você está deixando "lixo" na memória ao longo do tempo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186644/como-identificar-e-evitar-memory-leak-no-net

Comment: Obrigada vou dar uma pesquisada em memory leak e nas dicas pra ver se acho o problema rsrs